# Cross join two lists java

Tags: list, java-8, nested-loops

I have a class ABC which contains two integer fields

```
public class ABC{
  private Integer x;
  private Integer y;

   // getters and setters
}
```

I have two lists : xValues and yValues, which contain list of integers of x and y values respectively.

```
List<Integer> xValues = fetchAllXValues();  //say list xValues contains {1,2,3}
List<Integer> yValues = fetchAllYValues();  //say list yValues contains {7,8,9}
```

Now what I want is to create an ABC object using each values of xValues list with each values of yValues list. I dont want to use nested for loop. What would be a more efficient way to solve this?

sample output objects for ABC are:

```
     ABC(1,7);
     ABC(1,8);
     ABC(1,9);
     ABC(2,7);
     ABC(2,8);
     ABC(2,9);
     ABC(3,7);
     ABC(3,8);
     ABC(3,9);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Iterate over the first list and on every iteration iterate over the second list:

```
xValues.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> yValues.stream().map(y -> new ABC(x, y)))
    .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Doesn't lambda expression require constants in its evaluation? I will try this once and come back to you

Comment: @AkashRaveendran what do you mean `lambda expression require constants in its evaluation`?

Comment: once I used lambda expression to in forEach function. But I used to get an error that I cant use changing values for a field inside lambda expression. It used to ask me to change the field to a static final. Thats why I asked you Doesn't lambda expression require constants  in its evaluation. However when I tried out this code now, there was no such error.

Comment: @AkashRaveendran yea, you're right. you can't change values outside of  lambda. and in this code, you don't do it

Comment: Can I add an increment value in this flatMap function too? Like I have an increment value 'i' which I initialize to 1 for each 'x' in flatMap and for each 'y' in the map I increment 'i' on each object of 'yValues' list.

Comment: @AkashRaveendran no. you should find other ways

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118311/discussion-between-akash-raveendran-and-sergey-lagutin).

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using a third party library, you could use [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) which has rich and concise APIs directly available under collections.

```
MutableList<Integer> xValues = ListAdapter.adapt(fetchAllXValues());  
MutableList<Integer> yValues = ListAdapter.adapt(fetchAllYValues());  

xValues.flatCollect(x -> yValues.collect(y -> new ABC(x, y)));
```

`flatCollect()` here is equivalent to Java 8 streams `flatMap()`. Similarly `collect()` is equivalent to `map()`

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this you can also use some external libs, for example with StreamEx it will look like:

```
    StreamEx.of(xValues).cross(yValues)
      .map(entry -> new ABC(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```