# Combining Two Different Lists Holding Different Objects in to Third List holding Object as Cross Join of Two Lists

Tags: java, list, lambda, stream

I have List of Objects. Each object holds a List of Long and a List of JsonNode.
What I am trying to do is create a third List with Object, wherein each Object is the result of a cross join between the above two Lists.

E.g.

```
class MyClass{
    List<Long> _listLong;
    List<JsonNode> _listJsonNode;
}
```

I have List of MyClass Objects. What I want is to create a List of MyClass.

```
class MyClass2{
    Long id;
    JsonNode jsonNode;
}
```

such that `List<MyClass2>` holds the result of a cross join of `List<Long>` and `List<JsonNode>`.

I am able to do the same using loops.
Is there a way to achieve the same using Streams in Java?

Comment: And by "cross-join", you actually mean a Cartesian product? Or is it rather a 1 to 1 mapping in the order of the two lists?

Comment: @ernest_k - yes i mean Cartesion Product

Comment: Duplicate of [Cross join two lists java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568550/cross-join-two-lists-java)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting with a list of `MyClass` objects, you have to flatten it and use two nested streams for the Cartesian product.

```
List<MyClass2> result = myClassList.stream().flatMap(
   mc -> mc.get_listLong()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(i -> mc.get_listJsonNode()
                                .stream()
                                .map(js -> new MyClass2(i, js))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That assumes the constructor `MyClass2(Long, JsonNode)` exists. The inner `flatMap` is creating the required Cartesian product, by essentially iterating over all `JsonNode` elements for each `Long` element.

Comment: something is missiing is this code, i tried  but it is not working

Comment: @GSK did you notice the remark about the constructor `MyClass2(Long, JsonNode)`? If that isn't the problem, what error are you getting?